# How to reference Rmd files which should be rendered (within a package function)

Tags: r, package

I write a package, which will be used to create automated reports.
There is one function `createPdfReport` which basically looks as follows (I use RStudio):

```
createPdfReport <- function(dataset, save_path) {
  rmdName <- strsplit(x = basename(dataset, split = ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]
  # some code here which uses "dataset"
  relPath <- dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)

  rmarkdown::render(input = paste0(relPath, "/myRMDfile.Rmd"),
                    output_dir = save_path,
                    output_file = paste0(rmdName , ".html"),
                    encoding = "UTF-8", quiet = TRUE)
}
```

Most likely, R will finally run on a server and it is not clear, which operating system or editor is used there.
Therefore, I would like to get rid of `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()`.
But how? I could not find anything.

`createPdfReport` is part of a typical package with the following structure:

- DESCRIPTION
- NAMESPACE
- /man
- /R

  - createPdfReport.R --> Contains the function createPdfReport() above
  - myRMDfile.Rmd
- /tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store `myRMDfile.Rmd` in `inst/extdata`, see [package raw data](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#sec-data-extdata).

This allows to get the file path and use it after package installation with:

```
system.file("extdata", "myRMDfile.Rmd", package = "myPackage")
```

Comment: Incredible, so clear and simple :-)